# How to implement sliding menu with animation effect for activity in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have checked this sliding menu library https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu they have used fragment and I have checked the navigation drawer. It doesn't have an animation effect. I want to implement a sliding menu with an animation effect for an activity instead of fragment.

Can anybody tell me what is the best way to implement this?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use translate plus scale animation and apply this to your parent layout of activity.

for example:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="+80%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Comment: How to bring two xml in single activity and animate like face book sliding menu